# Catholic teachings on the new life in resurrected body

Tags: catholicism, catholic-catechism

I have a question on life after the resurrection. After the resurrection, will our souls have a room to feel a desire for some things that doesn't necessarily have to do with God (such as desire to have a good friendship/relationship with other resurrected beings in heavenly state, or perhaps some thoughts like "I wish I had a chance to do certain things before I experienced my physical death, etc)? or will we desire God and God only as resurrected being, and nothing else?

Thank you,

Comment: While it can be some intense reading, John Paul II's 'Theology of the Body' contains some information on this, as well as lots of info on what mankind was like prior to the fall.

Answer (score 1):

The Catechism of the Catholic Church has this to say concerning the reserection of the dead.

http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p123a11.htm

Here is a breif excerpt from that page:
IN BRIEF

1015 "The flesh is the hinge of salvation" (Tertullian, De res. 8, 2:PL 2, 852). We believe in God who is creator of the flesh; we believe in the Word made flesh in order to redeem the flesh; we believe in the resurrection of the flesh, the fulfillment of both the creation and the redemption of the flesh.

1016 By death the soul is separated from the body, but in the resurrection God will give incorruptible life to our body, transformed by reunion with our soul. Just as Christ is risen and lives for ever, so all of us will rise at the last day.

1017 "We believe in the true resurrection of this flesh that we now possess" (Council of Lyons II: DS 854). We sow a corruptible body in the tomb, but he raises up an incorruptible body, a "spiritual body" (cf. 1 Cor 15:42-44).

1018 As a consequence of original sin, man must suffer "bodily death, from which man would have been immune had he not sinned" (GS § 18).

1019 Jesus, the Son of God, freely suffered death for us in complete and free submission to the will of God, his Father. By his death he has conquered death, and so opened the possibility of salvation to all men.

There is is more on the link.  There is no official understanding of what we will become when we are resurrected, the church does not say because it does not know the details of that transformation.  The only thing that can be known is that we will be much more than what we are or what we once were before the fall.

1 Cor 2:9 Eye hath not seen, nor ear heard, neither have entered into the heart of man, the things which God hath prepared for them that love him

The details of what we will become if we endure to the end, has not been revealed to us.  It is a Mystery, what is not a mystery is what the alternative might be if we fail to accept his Grace.

What is understood however is that there is Happyness, Joy, Love contentment.  These are things that we find glimpses of in this world but they are so strong and so powerful that we can't hold onto them.  I for example, remember the great Joy and love of seeing my Children born, or when I realized that God was real and true how I felt.  When we are content we do not seek for things that take us away from that contentment we embrace it, we hold on to it and in the resurrection, unlike in our present forms, we will be able to hold on to it.

It may be that wanting more than what is perfect was that which caused the fall.  "lust of the eyes, Lust of the flesh, Pride of life"

Heaven and our bodily reserection will be contentment, rather than it's counter which is the wishing of more than that.

I welcome any additions to this answer.